# computing PCA matrix for set of sift descriptors

Tags: matlab, sift, pca

I want to compute a general PCA matrix for a dataset, and I will use it to reduce dimensions of sift descriptors. I have already found some algorithms to compute it, but I couldn't find a way to compute it by using MATLAB.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[coeff, score] = princomp(X)
```

is the right thing to do, but knowing how to use it is a little tricky.

My understanding is that you did something like:

```
sift_image = sift_fun(img)
```

which gives you a binary image: sift_feature? 
(Even if not binary, this still works.)

**Inputs, formulating X:**

To use `princomp`/`pca` formulate X so that each column is a `numel(sift_image)` x 1 vector 
(i.e. `sift_image(:)`) 

Do this for all your images and line them up as columns in X. 
So X will be `numel(sift_image)` x num_images.

If your images aren't the same size (e.g. pixel dimensions different, more or less of a scene in the images), then you'll need to bring them into some common space, which is a whole different problem.

Unless your stuff is binary, you'll probably want to de-mean/normalize X, both in the column direction (i.e. normalizing each individual image) and row direction (de-meaning the whole dataset).

**Outputs**

`score` is the set of eigen vectors: it will be num_pixels * num_images. 
To get, say the first eigen vector back into an image shape, do:

```
first_component = reshape(score(:,1),size(im));
```

And so on for the rest of the components. There are as many components as input images.

Each row of `coeff` is the num_images (equal to num_components) set of weights that can be applied to generate each input image. i.e.

```
input_image_1 = reshape(score * coeff(:,1) , size(original_im));
```

where input_image_1 is the correct, original shape 
coeff(1,:) is a vector (num_images x 1) 
score is pixels x num_images
(Disclaimer: I may have the columns/rows mixed up, but the descriptions are correct.)

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the explanation that is really helpful, but what can I do to bring the images into common space?

Comment: The goal in bringing them into the same space is that they are the same size (pixel/voxel dimensions) and are aligned (aka registered).

Comment: (...continued from last post ...) Depending on your data, this could be pretty easy. MATLAB has a few things built in (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html), and I've seen a couple of things here on stack overflow. I deal with medical images, and use tools that are designed for those problems.

Comment: The images might have different number of SIFT vectors, so in that case how will X be framed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox, you can use the command `princomp`, or in recent versions the command `pca`.

Comment: I know the princomp function, but the problem is I couldn't get the "n-by-p data matrix X" part. I have an image dataset and I extracted the sift descriptors of them one by one with vl_sift function. In this situation what will be the data matrix X ?

Comment: I have no idea - it would depend how you've collected the sift descriptors and what you're planning to do with them. Typically with PCA you have `n` objects that you've collected `p` variables on, and you are reducing `p` variables to `q`, where `q<<p`. Perhaps you have `n` images, each with `p` sift descriptors measured? Or perhaps you have a single image with `n` regions of interest, each with `p` descriptors?